# Shell script double output. Simple log file and compund log file.

Tags: shell, unix

I have a DB status check for pre, during and post aplications. I need them to generate an individual log for each check (pre, during and post) and at the same time compose a big log with the output of all 3 runs. I can get each of the logs separetly but I don't know how to make the 2nd and 3rd checks save their outputs on an existing .log file (the 1st check log).

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks.

Comment: It was already solved using >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for tee?

```
echo "log 2" | tee -a 2.log 123.log
```

Appends `log 2` to both files 2.log and 123.log

Comment: Yes, that would be the exact command :). But I'm not quite sure where to place it

Comment: I dont quite understand, your script generates output to stdout just like echo does, isn't that it? So just do `mycommand | tee -a 2.log 123.log` and the pipe will pass the stdout of your command to `tee`.

Comment: I resolved it using >> to the logs.

exec 1>>${LOG} 

can you help me with the order? to append the at the bottom of the file?